# C: Converting int to String

Tags: c, string, int

In my code, I'd like to use string that denotes Will, Bob, Billy, Ryan or Ed instead of int. Specifically, using N strings S[1],S[2]...S[N] where S[I] the names above.

And also, input N is limited as following: (1 ≤ N ≤ 100,000)

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)

{

int input_num=0;
int isWill = 0;
int isBob = 0;
int isBilly = 0;
int isRyan = 0;
int isEd = 0;
int n=0;

scanf("%d", input_num);
printf("%d", input_num);

for(n;n<input_num;n++)
{
    char tmp[100,000];
    scanf("%s", tmp);

    if(tmp == "Will")
        isWill = 1;
    else if(tmp == "Bob")
        isBob = 1;
    else if(tmp == "Billy")
        isBlue = 1;
    else if(tmp == "Ryan")
        isRyan = 1;
    else if(tmp == "Ed")
        isEd = 1;

}
//end of input

if(isWill == 0)
    printf("Will\n");
if(isBob == 0)
    printf("Bob\n");
if(isBilly == 0)
    printf("Billy\n");
if(isRyan == 0)
    printf("Ryan\n");
if(isEd == 0)
    printf("Ed\n");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: So, whats the problem?

Comment: You need to update isWhite to isWill and so on... Also try using enums as they help switching between int and strings

Comment: You told us what you'd like to use, but haven't actually asked a question. Does your code not compile? What's the error message? Or does it not do what you want? What does it do? What do you want it to do? Where do you define `isWhite` et al? Why do you set `isWhite` but test for `isWill`? If you set `isWhite = 1` why do you test `if(isWill == 0)`? Those test opposite things.

Comment: I have edited my question! Changed isWhite to isWill. Thanks!

Comment: Remember to change isBlue to isBilly too! Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare strings, you need to use the `strcmp` library function, which returns 0 if the two argument strings are equal:

```
if ( strcmp( tmp, "Will" ) == 0 )
  // tmp contains the string "Will"
```

If you want an array of strings, you can do it one of two ways.  You can declare a 2d array, where the first dimension is tne number of names, and the second dimension is the max length of a name:

```
char names[NUMBER_OF_NAMES][MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
```

To copy a string, use `strcmp`:

```
strcmp( names[0], "Will" );
strcmp( names[1], "Bob" );
// etc.
```

Or, you can declare a 1D array, where each element is a *pointer* to a string:

```
char *names[NUMBER_OF_NAMES];

names[0] = "Will";
names[1] = "Bob";
```

Note that you're assigning a *pointer* value to `names[i]`; you're not copying the string contents to `names[i]`.

Finally, C doesn't recognize integer literals like `100,000`; you'll want to declare your `tmp` buffer as

```
char tmp[100000];
```

although that's somewhat large for a string buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Several things not quite as i would write them.
I had some minutes to spare and wrote a compiling example.
Maybe your problems can be solved by this.

```
char * colortext[] =
{
    "unknown",
    "white",
    "black",
    "blue",
    "red",
    "yellow"
};

typedef enum color { 
    unknown = 0,
    white,
    black,
    blue,
    red,
    yellow
};

typedef struct
{
    int number;
    char name[200];
    color team;
}Player;

typedef struct
{
    char * name;
    color team;
}Autoassign;

Autoassign autoassign[] =
{
    {"Will", white},
    {"Bob", black},
    {"Billy", blue},
    {"Ryan", red},
    {"Ed", yellow}
};

int autoassignLength = sizeof(autoassign) / sizeof(autoassign[0]);

int Player_print(Player * player)
{
    int e = 0;
    printf("\n");
    printf("Player %i Profile:\n", player->number);
    printf("Name: '%s'\n", player->name);
    printf("Team: '%s'\n", colortext[player->team]);
    printf("\n");
    return e;
}

int Player_scan(Player * player, int number)
{
    int e = 0;
    int i;
    printf("Input Player Name: ");
    scanf("%s", player->name);
    player->number = number;
    player->team = unknown;
    for(i = 0; i < autoassignLength; ++i)
    {
        if(0 == strcmp(player->name,autoassign[i].name))
        {
            player->team = autoassign[i].team;
            break;
        }
    }
    return e;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i;
    int input_num, n;
    Player players[10];

    printf("How many Players? ");
    scanf("%d", &input_num);

    for(n = 0; n < input_num ; n++)
    {
        Player_scan(&players[n], n+1);
    }

    for(n = 0; n < input_num ; n++)
    {
        Player_print(&players[n]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make compare strings that's not the way to go.
Use `string.h` library to be able to use the function `strcmp` .
To use this functions type `strcmp(string1, string2)`
Just remember that strcmp will return 0 if the strings are equal.
So what you want to do is use `if(!strcmp("Will", tmp))` to enter the if  when the strings are the same.

You also need to change char `tmp[100,000]` `to char tmp[100000]`, for this is the supported format in C.

Hope this helps.